# Counts from aggregating on a time period for poisson modeling

Tags: data-transformation, poisson-regression

I have a data set where each observation is a count==1. I also have common demographic data for each observation such as SEX, AGE, etc. I also have a time stamp variable, HOUR. I would like to fit the data to a poisson model. My plan is to take aggregate counts by taking the sum of observations by HOUR. With that said, how do I treat the demographic data? Should the new data set have the sum of counts for MALE, FEMALE, AGE-GROUPS? Or, should should there be multiple rows for each HOUR based upon the various demographic characteristics? So, the sum of various demographics would have one observation, or row, per HOUR while the stratified may have multiple rows per HOUR.

TIA.